# Popup display not working with alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco-share

I have a problem with the following code:

```
                    this.widgets.boiteForm.setAJAXSubmit(true, {
                    successCallback: {
                        fn: function(){
                            Alfresco.util.PopupManager.displayMessage({
                                text: Alfresco.util.message(this.msg("message.send.success")),
                                displayTime: 2
                            });
                            YAHOO.lang.later(5000,this,Alfresco.util.navigateTo($siteURL("dashboard")) );
                        },
                        scope: this
                    },
                    failureMessage: this.msg("message.send.failure"),
                    failureCallback: {
                        fn: this.onFormSubmitFailure,
                        scope: this
                    },
                    obj: {attachementsRefs: this.attachementsRefs}
                });
```

When the submit succeeds, The popup doesn't display but the navigate kicks in. I'm not able to figure out what could be causing this issue.

Comment: more info, log, console, etc..

Comment: @alaeddine.nasri The only thing that shows up anywhere is in the browser console. For that, I get a "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead." warning in the console logs. I don't know what else I could possibly give other than this.